# Broken image (square) uploaded on server: What am I missing?

Tags: php, function, drawing

```
<html>
<header><title>My Square</title><header>
<body>
<?php 

/* Build a square of supplied colour. */

// Call the function creating a square of 110 pixels with colour of green.
square(110, 0, 200, 0);

// Define the function that builds the square. The parameters are size in pixels and the red, green, blue colour intensity.

function square ($size, $r, $g, $b) {
// Output the header telling the browser this is a png image.
header ('Content-type: image/png');

// create the empty image.
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');

/* Define the foreground and background colours and fill the image with the bacground colour.
The foreground colour is passed as a parameter, the background colour is white */
$fgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,255,255);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bgcolor); 

// Draw a rectangle. The upper left coordinate is 0,0. The lower right is size-1, size-1 since we started counting at 0. 
imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, $size-1, $size-1, $fgcolor);

/* Write the image to standard out - in the case of the web server to the network to the browser
and free up any memory used by the image */
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
}
?>
</body>
<html>
```

I cannot seem to get my image to display online, I need to figure out how to draw two of these within the same function as well. I am creating a simple square image with background color to the canvas and color fill within the circle. I just cannot seem to get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the browser that it is to expect HTML and not am image/png (html tags).

Remove your HTML code and just have some php code.  If you want to separate it into another file "square.php" then have your header() tell the browser what type of file it is:

```
header ('Content-type: image/png');
```

Your reformatted file

```
    <?php 

    /* Build a square of supplied colour. */

    // Call the function creating a square of 110 pixels with colour of green.
    square(110, 0, 200, 0);

    // Define the function that builds the square. The parameters are size in pixels and the red, green, blue colour intensity.

    function square ($size, $r, $g, $b) {
    // Output the header telling the browser this is a png image.
    header ('Content-type: image/png');

    // create the empty image.
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');

    /* Define the foreground and background colours and fill the image with the bacground colour.
    The foreground colour is passed as a parameter, the background colour is white */
    $fgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
    $bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 255,255,255);
    imagefill($im, 0, 0, $bgcolor); 

    // Draw a rectangle. The upper left coordinate is 0,0. The lower right is size-1, size-1 since we started counting at 0. 
    imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, $size-1, $size-1, $fgcolor);

    /* Write the image to standard out - in the case of the web server to the network to the browser
    and free up any memory used by the image */
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect thanks guys took out the html, and for whatever reason it works now when it didn't before, thanks for the help and so quickly its much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

working fine in [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kwu-36p)

or specify the `header ('Content-type: image/png');`